# Bernoulli Related Probability Distribution

Tags: probability, self-learning

1. Find the probability of having $4$ or more girls in a family of $6$ children.
2. Find also the probability that among $5$ families, each with $6$ children, at least $3$
   of the families have $4$ or more girls.
3. An urn contains $4$ white and $3$ black balls. Balls are randomly selected, one at a
   time, until a black one is obtained. If we assume that each selected ball is replaced
   before the next one is drawn, what is the probability that at least $4$ draws are
   needed?
4. Suppose that $25%$ of the items taken from a production line are defective. If the
   items taken from the line production are checked until 10 defective items are found.
   What is the probability that $15$ items are examined?

For question $1$, is the required probability $3/64$? I just find it out by the calculating the sum of $(0.5)^4 x (0.5)^2 + (0.5)^5 x (0.5) + (0.5)^6$

For question $2$, is the required probability $9.84 x 10^-5$? The method I adopted is similar to the above one.

For question $3$, is that $1 - (3/7 + 4/7 x 3/7 + 4/7 x 4/7 x 3/7 ) = 64/343 $?

Lastly, for question $4$, how do I find the required probability? Please advise me.

Answer (score 0):

(1) also needs to account for the order of births of the children. clearly, probability of having 0,1,...,or 6 girls should be 1 but by your logic you get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^6 0.5^k 0.5^{6-k} = 7 \cdot 0.5^6 = 7/64 \neq 1
$$

(2) indeed the method should be similar - need to account for the order also

(3) looks correct to me

(4) look at the [Negative Binomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) distribution